# C# Command parser

Tags: c#, parsing, console, command

im currently expanding my knowledge a little, and wanted to Create a little game for myself.

The Structure is as Following:
Programm.cs creates an instance of Gamecontroller. This Gamecontroller is the lowest level i want to Access. It will create instaces of the Views, and from classes like config.

I want to implement an debug Console with Command Input. These Commands should always start at the Gamecontroller level, and should be able to interact with kinda everything i could do with C# code.

So i want to access the Objects, Member and methods withing Gamecontroller, or Within any nested object.

Currently i cant get to the Properties of an Child, because _member returns an "Type" which gets parsed to RuntimeProperty instead of the Class

Example on Parsing:

```
"objPlayer.name" > "GameController.objPlayer.name"
"objConfig.someSetting = 10" > "GameController.objConfig.someSetting=10"
"objConfig.functionCall()" > "GameController.objConfig.functionCall()"
"objConfig.objPlayer.setName("someName")" > "GameController.objConfig.objPlayer.setName("someName")"
"objPlayer.name" > "GameController.objPlayer.name"
```

this is what i got so far:

```
    private void parseComamnd(string Command)
    {
        var actions = Command.Split('.');
        var start = this.GetType();
        var last = actions[actions.Length - 1];
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            if (action.Contains("(") && action.Contains(")"))
            {
                _exec(start, action);
            }
            else
            {
                start = _member(start, action);
            }
        }
    }
    private Type _member(Type pHandle, string pStrMember)
    {
        return pHandle.GetProperty(pStrMember).GetType();
    }
    private void _exec(Type pHandle, string pStrFunction)
    {
        var Regex = new Regex(@"\(|,|\)");
        var FunctionParams = Regex.Split(pStrFunction);
        var FunctionName = FunctionParams[0];
        FunctionParams[0] = "";
        FunctionParams = FunctionParams.Where(val => val != "").ToArray();
        pHandle.GetMethod(FunctionName).Invoke(FunctionName, FunctionParams);
    }
```

Comment: So, what the question about? Do you want to implement own DSL for game? If you want to be able to run c#-like commands via debug console, take a look on Roslyn. If U want to parse own commands, U can use antlr or custom written parser.

Comment: I didn't understand what's your question/doubts. If you want to do your own DSL I suggest you have a look at => http://goldparser.org
You can create you own language, check syntax and generate code based on the input.

Comment: For my Console i thought about smth like PHP eval, i dunno what a dsl is yet tbh, found a text about dsl, and im working through it right now :) - i would like it to behave like that Live Console in debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to match some string commands with actions you want to perform. In this case you could use Dictionary as a storage for string-delgate couples to match your string commands to actions you want to perform. As an advantage of this approach, you can change matched couples during program runtime as you wish

```
class SomeClass
{
    delegate void OperationDelegate(string value);
    IDictionary<string, OperationDelegate> Operations = new Dictionary<string, OperationDelegate>();

    public SomeClass()
    {
        Operations.Add("objPlayer.name", SetName);
        Operations.Add("objConfig.someSetting", SetSetting); 
    }

    public void HandleNewValue(string command, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Operations.ContainsKey(command))
                Operations[command](value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e);
        }
    }

    private void SetName(string value)
    {
        // Some logic there
    }

    private void SetSetting(string value)
    {
        // Some logic there
    }
}
```

Comment: this could actualy be enought for me. I was bound to the eval thinking of PHP, so i might give this a try.